# How to create d3 svg in vue-cli?

Tags: d3.js, charts, vue.js

I'm new to d3 and trying to create d3 SVG in vue-cli.

the browser does not show anything with the code as below, but it work on HTML without vue.

Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

Thank you very much!

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div id='chart' ></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3'

  export default {
    name: 'priceChart',
    data() {
      return {
     }
    },
  methods:{
    createSvg(){
    const svg = 
    d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',400);

    svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',400)
    .style('fill','red')
    }
   },
 created(){
   this.createSvg();
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM element is not available in `created` methods, you should put it in `mounted`

> In the created hook, you will be able to access reactive data and
>   events are active. Templates and Virtual DOM have not yet been mounted
>   or rendered.

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div id='chart' ></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3'

  export default {
    name: 'priceChart',
    data() {
      return {
     }
    },
  methods:{
    createSvg(){
    const svg = 
    d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',400);

    svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',400)
    .style('fill','red')
    }
   },
 mounted(){
   this.createSvg();
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!

Comment: To avoid collisions with multiple `id`’s, you can replace `<div id="chart">` and `d3.select("#chart")` by `<div ref="chart">` and `d3.select(this.$refs.chart)` respectively.